# How to unsquash and mount arch linux live CD

Tags: installation, arch-linux

I am following [this manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_Existing_Linux#Use_Arch_Linux_Live_CD_Root_Image_as_Host_System) to install Arch Linux from within another Linux distro with the help of an Arch Linux live CD. Here is what I did:

- `sudo mount -o loop Downloads/archlinux-2012.11.01-dual.iso arch_iso/`
- `unsquashfs -d squashfs-root/ arch_iso/arch/x86_64/root-image.fs.sfs`
- This results in a directory `squashfs-root/` containing one file: `root-image.fs`

I assume that this is not what I want. I want to see something that looks like a Linux root folder. If I follow these steps: "mount the file system" with `mount -B /squashfs-root ${livecd_arch}` and `mount -t proc /proc ${livecd_arch}/proc`, I get error messages like:

```
mount: mount point /home/me/arch_root//proc does not exist
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a directory before you can mount anything to it. The error that mount is throwing appears to reflect such a situation. To rectify it, simply create the directory:

```
mkdir /home/me/arch_root/proc
```

Then retry your mount command.

Comment: That was my first guess, but it turns out that these directories are supposed to be there... see my self-answer. 1up for being the only one who cared ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mounting the directory with

```
mount -B /squashfs-root ${livecd_arch}
```

On has to mount the file in it with

```
mount squashfs-root/root-image.fs arch_root/
```

Then I end up with what would become the root folder of the live system with existing but obviously empty /proc (etc.) folders. That's where I mount the host systems /proc into.